# Problema de formatação de data laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, datapicker

Estou tentando resolver um problema de formatação de data antes de enviar para o banco de dados mas não estou tendo sucesso!

Estou usando em um formulário o plugin datapicker, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: input data picker]

No meu Controller eu tenho essa linha de código:

```
$agenda_exame->data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->data_exame));
```

E está salvando a data no banco dessa forma: **1969-12-31**

Onde está o o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente sua data esta indo com '/', no php vc precisa substituir por '-'
exemplo:

```
$data = '27/02/2018';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data)));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, resolveu o problema!